# Update an already open window or url

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created an online portal using HTML, javascript and php to creates table and chart from database, just like MS excel.The online portal is just some set of forms where I give the inputs and submit the charts will be prepared in a new window. Now I want a functionality where I can append more charts and reports to the same opened window. Can anyone tell me how can I achive this.

Comment: Have the opened window poll a PHP file, and if there is anything new, have it be updated automatically. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) are references on AJAX. A timestamp can be sent when requesting to know which data have been updated already.

Comment: The (really) short answer ajax.

Comment: Just add the charts and reports to the same opened window.  That's how.  Oh, if you wanted code... maybe show some?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing, including all error messages. See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: All I need is some directions and pointers as to how I can get this functionality. If someone can give me some examples to open an empty window and update the same window with new elements, I can take it from there I hope. I dont have any errors to show as I am trying this for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning in your post if you are using any JavaScript library, therefore I will make some suggestions that might help build web applications faster and easier.

You can open content through a Dialog Widget, this is the documentation link:

- Open content in an interactive overlay: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

These are a few helpful links if you want to learn about using jQuery:

- jQuery learning center: https://learn.jquery.com/
- jQuery Ajax: https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
- jQuery getJSON: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
- a fast way to learn jQuery basics through an online free course: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery
- jQuery UI API: https://api.jqueryui.com/

These are a few links for learning AngularJS, for getting dynamic views:

- AngularJS documentation: http://angularjs.org/
- quick start with AngularJS: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-how_to_start.html